# How would you get a random number where the first and last digits differ by more than one?

Tags: java

I need to generate a random 3-digit number where the first digit and the third digit differ by more than one. How would I accomplish this *without arrays*, as simply as possible? I am still a beginner.

```
int num = 0;

int firstDigit = 0;
int lastDigit = 0;

// complete the method

//while loop
while(firstDigit-lastDigit<1)
{
    num = (int)(Math.random() * (999-100) + 100);
    String number = String.valueOf(num);
    String n1 = number.substring(0,1);
    String n2 = number.substring(2,3);
    int a = Integer.parseInt(n1);
    int b = Integer.parseInt(n2);
    
    firstDigit = a;
    lastDigit = b;
    int randNum = Math.abs(a-b);
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);   
}
```

I at first tried this, but soon realized that the while loop was simply always active, because it was getting its initial values from when they were defined earlier in the method.

Comment: `int num = ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(100, 1000).filter(n -> Math.abs(n / 100 - n % 10) > 1).findFirst().getAsInt();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with using a loop (or infinite stream) to get to a result, is that your execution time becomes unpredictable, and that, *theoretically* speaking, your function could run infinitely.

Here's a straightforward approach that generates a random<sup>(*)</sup> number within your constraints on the first try:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      Random random = new Random();
        
      int first = random.nextInt(1, 10);
      int middle = random.nextInt(0, 10);
      int last = (first + random.nextInt(2, 9)) % 10;
      int result = first * 100 + middle * 10 + last;
      
      System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

This solution relies on the fact that for the last digit, there's only 7 possible values to choose from. It generates a random value between 2 and 8, adds that to the first digit, and then uses a modulo operation to reduce back to a single digit.

---

<sup><sup>(*)</sup> There are two caveats here: 1) The generated results are random up to the point that the used [pseudo-random number generator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) produces random numbers. 2) Your last digit will be biased towards the `9`, `0` and `1` values which are 16.66...% more likely to occur due to the exclusion of the `0` value from the first digit. Other solutions will show the same bias.</sup>

Comment: _"... theoretically speaking ..."_; I didn't know there was a theorem regarding syntax errors.  I'm just kidding, great solution.

Comment: @Reilas Where do you spot a syntax error? Compiles and runs fine for me.

Comment: Yes, that bias exists but isn't that just the nature of this problem? i.e. wouldn't the set of all numbers that meet this condition be "biased" like this?

Comment: @Shifu Yes. That's why I noted that other solutions would show the same bias. It's due to the exclusion of the `0` in the first position. You could compensate it by sacrificing some randomness. I added the clarification because the exclusion of the `0` was not explicitly stated in the question (it was just apparent from the code). Up to OP to figure out what's more important.

Answer (score 1):

```
Random random = new Random();

int first = random.nextInt(1, 10);
int last = random.nextInt(3, 10);
last = switch (last - first) {
    case 1 -> 0;
    case 0 -> 1;
    case -1 -> 2;
    default -> last;
};
int middle = random.nextInt(0, 10);
System.out.println(first * 100 + middle * 10 + last);
```

I think this variant will be the simplest one for the beginner. It doesn't use arrays, streams and cycles

Comment: Simple, yes. Random number within the constraints given, no.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I've missed the part, about differ more then one. I've edited code, I think, now it works fine)

Comment: The edited code still does not always produce a number within the constraints.

Comment: When? The corner cases may be 2 or 3, but code solves them too, other digits are not scary for us

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as follows.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int n = getRandom();
    System.out.printf("%d ", n);
}
```

prints something like

```
592 842 522 167 760 521 318 178 466 632
```

Just create the `first`, `last`, and middle digits to conform to the required delta. Check out [Random](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#Random()) for details on the available methods.

- generate `first` from `1 to 9` inclusive
- Then generate `last` so it is at least `2` from `first`. This uses the [conditional operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3.1.4) `?:`
- the middle part is just `10 to 90` inclusive.

```
import java.util.Random;
Random r = new Random();
  
public static int getRandom() {
    int first = r.nextInt(1, 10);
    int last = first < 5 ? r.nextInt(6, 9) : r.nextInt(0, 3);
    return (first * 100) + r.nextInt(10)*10 + last;
}
```

Keep in mind that these may not be purely random numbers from a mathematical perspective.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to go about this problem. The way I can think of that would be most similar to your attempt would be this:

```
// first and second digit can be anything
int firstDigit = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
int secondDigit = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
int thirdDigit;

// generate a random digit until the condition is met
do {
    thirdDigit = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
} while (Math.abs(firstDigit - thirdDigit) <= 1);

int result = firstDigit * 100 + secondDigit * 10 + thirdDigit;
```

This is a great example of how you would use the [do-while loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html).

Another possible solution is to use Java's [ThreadLocalRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html). You would first need to include the class:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
```

Then, your solution would be:

```
int result = ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(100, 1000).filter(n -> Math.abs(n / 100 - n % 10) > 1).findFirst().getAsInt();
```

`ThreadLocalRandom.current()` returns the thread's current instance of this object. `.ints(100, 1000)` returns a stream of random integers in the range [100, 1000), i.e. random 3-digit numbers. `.filter(n -> Math.abs(n / 100 - n % 10) > 1)` can be confusing for a beginner. Basically, for each number `n` in this (effectively) infinite stream, we only want the numbers that meet the condition `Math.abs(n / 100 - n % 10) > 1`. Notice that `n / 100` rounded down will always be the first digit of a 3-digit, positive, base-10 number, and `n % 10` (n modulus 10) will always be the last digit of a positive, base-10 integer. `.findFirst()` will get the first number in the stream that meets the filter's condition. This is returned as an [OptionalInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalInt.html), which allows for error handling. In this case, though, we can simply call `.getAsInt()` to obtain the value.

If you are able to understand the second option then I would recommend using it, but if the first one makes more sense to you then use that. My advice is to never use code that you can't explain!

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I need to generate a random 3-digit number where the first digit and the third digit differ by more than one. ..."*

Here is an example.

```java
Random r = new Random();
int x, a = r.nextInt(1, 10), b = r.nextInt(1, 10), c;
while (Math.abs(a - (c = r.nextInt(1, 10))) <= 1);
x = (a * 100) + (b * 10) + c;
```

And, here are some example outputs.

```
684, 874, 114, 512, 459, 267, 451, 779, 751, 691
```

Comment: I think you need to import java util for Random class.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Simple{  
    public static void main(String args[]){
        boolean noGap = true  ;
        int a = ((int) (Math.random()*10));
        int b = ((int) (Math.random()*10));
        int c = 0 ; 
        while(noGap){
            c = ((int) (Math.random()*10));
            if(a>c){
                noGap = a-c>1 ? false:true ;  
            }
            if(c>a){
                noGap = c-a>1 ? false:true ; 
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Integer.toString(a)+Integer.toString(b)+Integer.toString(c));
    }
}
```

No need for any import.

Comment: *"Require no library except the native one."* Not sure I get your point. None of the answers posted in this thread so far requires an external library. Do you mean a [package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/package.html)? If so, the `java.util` package is as much part of the standard library as the `java.lang` package.